# CSS - Smaller header font size if overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlap

How  can I decrease my header's font size if it is overlapping with another element?

I am currently using: `word-break: break-all;` but overlapping still exists.

P.S. I am still a beginner, sorry if this question sounds too easy.

My code:

```
.container{ position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 5%; }
```

and

```
.container2{ position: absolute; bottom: 0; margin-bottom: 30px; width: 100%; }
```

Basically, when I have a `<h2>` in .container and if the text is too long it will overlap on the `<h2>` text which is in .container2. How do I avoid this or resize the text properly?

Comment: Can you post your HTML code to see which are the elements that overlap?

Comment: `        .container{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 5%;
        }` and `        .container2{
            position: absolute; 
            bottom: 0; 
            margin-bottom: 30px; 
            width: 100%;
        }`

Basically, when my first container has a heading which is too long it will overlap over my second container and I wish to resize it so it does not do so.

Comment: Please edit your question to post your codes. Codes in comment box is hard to read & almost unable to format.

Comment: i have edited my question and included the code in there.

Comment: We need to see the related HTML codes, @JasonKryschwaski

Comment: Post your Html Please

Comment: @JasonKryschwaski.  Maybe set width on .container?  and change width on .container2 to the remainder of 100%?  ie if .container is 40% set .container2 to 60%.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div#header{
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
    color: rgb(41, 40, 40);
    background-color: rgb(248, 248, 248);
}

p{
    font-size: 50pt;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(63, 61, 61);
    font-style: normal;
   font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
p1{
    font-size: 20pt;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(63, 61, 61);
    font-style: normal;
   font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
        <div class="header">
        TEXT
            <p>TEXT</p>
            <p1>TEXT</p1>
        </div>
```

Comment: Don't mind css margin: 0; and font-variant: normal; being out of line

Comment: I do not seem to understand what this represents. Could you tell me on which part of this code should I focus in order to change mine?

Comment: This is *all wrong*. Don't invent new tags like `<p1>` and the codes are not related to the question at all.